# Invalid data length for VarChar, VarByte, or VARGRAPHIC using Ado.Net connector SqlServer-Teradata

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, teradata

I have to insert some data from SQL Server to a Teradata Server, using a SSIS package.
For SQL Server I have used OleDb Source (by variable) for retrieving the data and for Teradata I have used an Ado.Net connector to write the data into Teradata tables.

But for one table I have the error

> Invalid data length for VarChar, VarByte, or VARGRAPHIC

when starting the dataflow.

If I preview the values from OleDb source, copy them into a Teradata SQL Assistant and write the insert query, it works, but when the SSIS package tries to insert the data, it gives me the

> Invalid data length for VarChar, VarByte, or VARGRAPHIC

error and stops.

I have check the web, but cannot find anything that works, I have check that SQL statement does not have any Null values (used -1 as Null).

Any hints?

Comment: It seams that no matter what type of varchar variable I have used, the error was the same. The only way I could resolve this was to change data conector, so instead of ADO.Net I have used Attunity, for Sql Server and Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

I found by adding 2 spaces to the front and back of the (n)varchar values fixed this. I didn't need a ISNULL statement on the original clause. I got the tip from: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/teradata-invalid-data-length-varchar-44224.aspx